This is my first project on react . In this blog site project I want to get data from custom hook component and output in another page by specific id
First I made a custom hook and put the useState array in this file
this is Output page, in this page I tried to get the data from custom hook and output the data from useState array filtered by id:
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import useFetch from '../../../../Hooks/UseFetch';


const BlogView = () => {

  const { id } = useParams('');
  const { blog } = useFetch('/'+ id );
  console.log(blog);
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <article >
        <h2>Title {blog.title}</h2>
        <p>{id}</p>
        <p>Author Name: {blog.author}</p>
        <div>Body: {blog.body} </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BlogView

I tried to use the the filter method to get filtered data. but it shows some error.
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import useFetch from '../../../../Hooks/UseFetch';


const BlogView = () => {

  const { id } = useParams('');
  const { blog } = useFetch();
  const data = {blog.filter((blog)=> blog.id == id)}
  
  console. log (data)
  return (
    <div>
      <article>
        <h2>Title {data.title}</h2>
        <p>{id}</p>
        <p>Author Name: {data.author}</p>
        <div>Body: {data.body} </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BlogView```


Please edit the question to provide a [mre] and adjust the title to summarize the issue or question.
